# What does TypeError: stream.listeeners is not a function mean?

Tags: node.js, firebase, unit-testing, jestjs, google-cloud-functions

I am unit testing firebase onRequest cloud function with jest

This is the test code:

```
const index = require ('./index')

describe ('test function', () => {
  it('positive case', async () => {
    let req = { "usn": "cmu2010"}
    let res = { "response": "hi cmu"}
    index.myCloudFunction(req, res)
  });
});
```

This is my index.js file:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp();
const importFile = require('./myCloudFunction')
exports.myCloudFunction = importFile.myCloudFunction
```

Inside myCloudFunction.js, I have my cloud function written in express

```
const functions = require ("firebase-functions")
myCloudFunction.post("/", async(request, response) => {
  // 
})
exports.myCloudFunction = functions.https.onRequest(myCloudFunction)
```

I am getting TypeError: stream.listeners is not a function
What does it mean and where am I going wrong? I have searched for this error but there aren't any good explanation available.

Comment: add the index file contents to the question

Comment: Can you share more code snippet?

Comment: @MahtabAlam I have added index file

Comment: @RoopaM I have added the other files

Comment: Seems like you are trying to attach a listener to an object that is not a stream. Try ```const stream = require('stream');
const index = require ('./index')

describe ('test function', () => {
  it('positive case', async () => {
    let req = { "usn": "cmu2010"}
    let res = new stream.PassThrough();
    index.myCloudFunction(req, res)
  });
}); ```

Comment: @RoopaM how will I pass my actual response?

Comment: You can try this `let res = { "response": "hi cmu"}
const bufferStream = new PassThrough();
   bufferStream.pipe(res);` too

Comment: @RoopaM I tried it but it's dest.on is not a function error. I am thinking is it because of the way I am calling express? I am using post("/"). For such call is the way I have written the test code correct?